# Writing File to a directory using java.io.File.mkdirs() and then accessing it not working in spark cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When i try to run the same code in client mode, the code runs successfully. But when run on cluster mode it fails to create the file and prompts with error No such File or Directory.

Below is the code sample:

```
new File("UnexistingLocation").mkdirs()
```

---> Directories created in client mode

---> Code do not give error in cluster mode but i cannot see directory created. Also while creating File inside the directory gives error No such file or Directory.

Is there a workaround by which i could create files on driver node local filesystem?

Comment: As @DominicEgger said, the folder will be created in any random node, and maybe the code that tries to create a file inside the folder is running in other node _(without code we can't be sure of that)_. Also, why exactly do you want to write a local file with Spark, wouldn't a distributed file system, like HDFS or S3 be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

due to your error analysis I assume this is run in driver-scoped code. If you submit using `--deploy-mode cluster` your driver will be started on an arbitrary node which means that's where your directory will be. It won't be on the node where you do your `spark-submit` from